# Bootstrap site not responding properly on iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've started building a site for a friend, looks great on desktop, and great when I change the browser window size but seems to be zoomed out when I open it on my iPhone?

Any ideas why? Here's the link to the temporary site, if you change browser size to mobile that's how it should look.

http://torwood.footholds.net/~acoustic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header you have:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-with, initial-scale = 0.1">
```

which is telling it to start with an initial zoom of 10%

Change it to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**Edit:**

In fact, for best compatability you should include all the relevant  headers:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! Probably a ridiculously nooby question but I'm just beginning to learn bootstrap :) Thanks again! :D

Comment: No problem :) don't forget to click the tick button if it helps... thanks!